# How to gather multiple strings and input them into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

In c++, is it possible for me to make a loop, that asks the user to input information, and loop back to ask if they would like to keep adding information, until they dont. And store the values they typed into different parts of an array?

Ive been trying to use a while loop, but what happens is it will prompt if they want to add info, they select yes, they add it, if no, it puts into the terminal what they typed, but if I do yes twice, I just overwrite the first value, any way to correct this? I am quite new to programming and would appreciate any help, thank yo. (What I have is just a template to go off of, I know why it doesnt work, I also left out the preprocessor directives

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    string add;

    string name [100];

    while (true)
    {
        cout <<"Would you like to add a name? Yes or No? \n";
        getline(cin, add);
        if  (add == "yes" or add == "Yes")
            {
                cout<<"Enter a name\n";
                getline(cin, name); 
            }
        else if( add == "no" or add == "No")
            {break;}
        else
        {
            cout <<"sorry, that is not a valid response"<<endl<<endl;
        }
    }
    cout<<name;
    return 0;
}
```

I think trying to use pointers could work, but they have been confusing me haha. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: ***In c++, is it possible for me to make a loop, that asks the user to input information, and loop back to ask if they would like to keep adding information, until they dont. And store the values they typed into different parts of an array?*** Yes.

Comment: Hint: Maybe you want an integer as an index to your array. Start it off at 0 and increment after each item you add..

Comment: Stl vector or list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of std::vector can make your life easier here. See a code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string add;
string name;
vector<string> names;

while (true)
{
    cout <<"Would you like to add a name? Yes or No? \n";
    getline(cin, add);

    if  (add == "yes" or add == "Yes")
        {
            cout<<"Enter a name\n";
            getline(cin, name); 
            names.push_back(name);
        }
    else if( add == "no" or add == "No")
        {
          break;
         }
    else
    {
        cout <<"sorry, that is not a valid response"<<endl <<endl;
    }
}

// printing contents
for(auto n:names)
   cout << *n <<endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, Ill try this out as soon as I can, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use array Name with Index instead of variable name when store information like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    string add;

    string name [100];

    int index = 0; //Index Location of Array

    while (true)
    {
        cout <<"Would you like to add a name? Yes or No? \n";
        getline(cin, add);
        if  (add == "yes" or add == "Yes")
            {
                cout<<"Enter a name\n";
                getline(cin, name[index]); // write name with index to insert value in particular index
            }
        else if( add == "no" or add == "No")
            {break;}
        else
        {
            cout <<"sorry, that is not a valid response"<<endl<<endl;
        }
    }

    //loop here to output all value of name as mention above
    cout<<name;

    return 0;
}
```